# Good approach (php/jquery plugin) for handling multi file uploads: progress bar, option to remove, thumbnail creation

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, thumbnails

I have a site where users upload mostly PDF artwork and would like to:

- create a thumb of the 1st page, show it on successful upload
- show progress bar
- option to remove

Can anyone recommend a good approach, I realise it might need a mixture of jquery plugin and perhaps GD or imagemagick for PHP to create the thumbnail.